# C: create String existing out of ints and chars

Tags: c, string, char, int

Since I'm very new to C programming, I have a probably very simple problem.

I got a struct looking like this

```
typedef struct Vector{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}Vector;
```

Now I want to write an array of Vectors in a file. To achieve that, I thought to create following method scheme

```
String createVectorString(Vector vec){
    // (1)
}

String createVectorArrayString(Vector arr[]){
    int i;
    String arrayString;
    for(i=0; i<sizeof(arr); i++){
        //append createVectorString(arr[i]) to arrayString  (2)
    }
}

void writeInFile(Vector arr[]){
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("sorted_vectors.txt", "a+");
    fprintf(file, "%s", createVectorArrayString(arr);
    fclose(file);
}

int main(void){

    // create here my array of Vectors (this has already been made and is not part of the question)
    // then call writeInFile

    return 0;
}
```

My main problems are at (1), which involves also (2) (since I have no clue how to work with Strings in C, eclipse is saying "Type "String" unknown", although I included `<string.h>`)

So I read at some point that transforming an int to a String is possible with the method itoa().
As I understood it, I can simply do following

```
char buf[33];
int a = 5;
itoa(a, buf, 10)
```

However, I cannot bring that to work, let alone that I can't figure out how to "paste" `char`s or `int`s into a String.

In my point **(1)**, I would like to create a String of the Form `(a,b,c)`, where as a, b and c are the "fields" of my struct Vector.

In point **(2)**, I would like to create a single String of the Form `(a1,b1,c1)\n(a2,b2,c2)\n...(an,bn,cn)`, whereby n is the amount of Vectors in the array.

Is there a quick solution? Do I confuse the concept of Strings from Java with them of C?

Comment: If you included `<string.h>` (with a lowercase 's'), that provides some functions for working with C-strings, which are 0-terminated `char` arrays. There is no `String` (or `string`) type in standard C. If `String.h` is a header from your project defining a type `String`, we'd need to see that to understand the error.

Comment: you ar misunderstanding sizeof. `sizeof arr` will not do what you expect.

Comment: that was a typo, corrected in question

Comment: @wildplasser you're right, I coded it hard now (12, as the arrays length is always 12)

Comment: If the size is variable, you should pass it as an extra parameter to the function. If it is really fixed, then it's fixed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you do confuse the concept of strings in Java and C.

The C strings are rather inconvenient to work with. They require dynamic memory allocation, and what is worse, corresponding deallocation (which is possible but tedious). In your case, it might be best to remove strings completely, and implement whatever you need without strings.

To write a vector directly to file:

```
Vector vec;
FILE* file = ...;
fprintf(file, "%d %d %\n", vec.a, vec.b, vec.c);
```

To write an array of vectors, just do the above in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

A string, in C, is just a null-terminated array of characters. It is generally declared as a `char *`, though if you have a fixed maximum length, and can allocate it on the stack or inline in a structure, it might be declared as `char str[LENGTH]`.

One of the easiest ways to build a string out of a mix of characters and numbers is to use `snprintf()`. This is like `printf()`, but instead of printing to standard output, will print into a string (an array of `char`). Note that you need to allocate and pass in the buffer yourself; so you will either need to know the maximum length beforehand, or find out by trying to call `snprintf()`, finding out how many characters it would print, allocating an array of that size, and calling `snprintf()` again to actually print the result.

So if you have a vector of three integers, and want to build a string out of it, you could write:

```
char *createVectorString(Vector vec){
    int count = snprintf(NULL, 0, "(%d,%d,%d)", vec.a, vec.b, vec.c);
    if (count < 0)
        return NULL;
    char *result = malloc(count * sizeof(char));
    if (result == NULL)
        return NULL;
    count = snprintf(result, count, "(%d,%d,%d)", vec.a, vec.b, vec.c);
    if (count < 0)
        return NULL;
    return result;
}
```

Note that because you called `malloc()` to allocate this buffer, you will need to call `free()` once you are done with it, to avoid a memory leak.

Note that `snprintf()` only returns the length that you need as of C99. Some compilers (like MSVC), don't support C99 yet, so they return -1 instead of the length that the string would be. In those cases, there may be another function that you can call to determine the size of buffer you need (in MSVC, it's `_vscprintf`), or you may need to just guess at a size, and if that doesn't work, allocate a buffer twice that size and try again, until it succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

In short: yes, you are confusing Java Strings with C, where you do not have standard string type. What is a string is in reality a sequence of chars terminated with a char with value 0 (or '\0', if you want to be purist).

The quickest solution is to not generate strings (and manually allocate all the memory), but rather to use `fprintf` with `FILE*`. Instead of functions to create strings, write functions to write various things into supplied `FILE*`, for example `int writeVector(FILE* output, Vector v)`. It will be easier for the beginning. I don't think all the gory details of manual memory management required for constructing such strings are good start.

(Note the return type of int in proposed prototype; this is for error codes.)

Additionally, as one of the commenters noted, you misunderstand sizeof. `sizeof(arr)` would return size of all the elements of the array combined, in bytes (well, technically in chars, but it's a distinction you don't need to worry about right now). To get number of elements in an array, you'd need to use `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])`. But I'm not sure it would work with your function argument, which is technically a pointer, despite the fancy syntax. Applying sizeof to pointer will return size of the pointer itself, not the data it points to.

Which is why in C you would usually provide size of an array in an extra function argument, like:

`String createVectorArrayString(Vector arr[], size_t n)`

or more in line with what I wrote above:

```
int writeVectorArray(FILE *output, Vector arr[], size_t n)
{
  int retcode = 0;
  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if ( (retcode = writeVector(output, arr[i])) != 0)
      return retcode;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you *are* confusing Java Strings with C.

1. you can't pass arrays in C, only pointers to the first element.
2. `sizeof (arr)` where arr is a function argument is the size of the pointer.
3. You can't return a block scope String, only a pointer to a string. But pointers to local automatic variables go out of scope when the function returns.

I'd write a loop more along

```
#define N 42

/* Typedef for Vector assumed somewhere.*/
Vector arr[N];
/* Fill arr[]. */

for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    fprintf (file, "arr[%d] =  { a=%d, b=%d, c=%d }\n", i, arr[i].a, arr[i].b, arr[i].c);
}
```